# Getting value form text box oop way

Tags: php, oop

This is my Method where I'm getting value.Everything is fine but I want to get the value using OOP.

such as Classname::methodname(name of textbox) this way.How Can i do this?

```
public function display()
{
    $name=$_POST['name'];
    $b=$_POST['email'];
    $c=$_POST['pass'];
    $d=$_POST['rpass'];
    $e=$_POST['phone'];

    $t=new User();

    $t->findEmail($b);
    $tt=$t->num_count();
    if($tt==0)
    {

    $t->username=$name;
    $t->email=$b;
    $t->pass=$c;
    $t->phone=$e;
    $t->save();

    // $ii=new Redirect();
    Redirect::to('register/success');   
    }
    else 
    {
    Redirect::to('register/Notsuccess');
    }

}
```

Comment: show what you've tried

Comment: I'm not sure how to do it.Please can you give me some suggestion? @treegarden

Comment: Work through [this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/object-oriented-php-for-beginners--net-12762) tutorial and you'll know how to do it.

Comment: Don't you think if you want to use oop way of getting values, you should create classes and functions to do that?

Comment: Yes I know that.But How can I get a value of a text box in this format?Should I write my Textbox in PHP tag? @KrisztiánDudás